# C++ crash Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c++, crash, segmentation-fault, runtime-error

I have been working on a program to test out a few string manipulation possibilities. It is basically supposed to read a string list and be able to find a character's neighbors to go through the strings as a circuit. Here's the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <fstream>

    std::string grid[20]={" "};

    std::string get(int string, int member){
      return grid[string].substr(member,1);
    }
    std::string* getNeighbors(int string, int member){
      std::string neighbors[4];
      neighbors[0]=grid[string-1].substr(member,1);//up
      neighbors[1]=grid[string+1].substr(member,1);//down
      neighbors[2]=grid[string].substr(member-1,1);//left
      neighbors[3]=grid[string].substr(member+1,1);//right
      std::string* p=neighbors;
      return p;//Returns up,down,left,right.
    }
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
      grid[1]="@----^---0";
      grid[2]="abcdefghi0";
      grid[3]="jklmnopqr0";//TODO Change to read of txt*/
      std::string* neighbors;
      for(int i=0;grid[1].length()>i;i++){
        neighbors=getNeighbors(2,1);
        if(neighbors[3]=="-" | neighbors[3]=="^"){
          std::string r=get(1,i);
          (r!="0") ? std::cout<<r:0;//Dangerous. TODO Unknown symbol handling
          std::cout<<neighbors[3];
        }
      }
    }
```

This compiles well, but has the runtime error "Segmentation fault: 11". I am using several subjects and techniques that I am not used to and am likely misusing. Any help would be great.

Comment: under what compiler it fails? with g++4.8 (after small fix - it didnt compile!), it works http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbc1a7134ee38989, but there is no output.

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that. I'm on a mac with 10.9 Mavericks with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79). I can stop the runtime error by removing every call and reference of the getNeighbors(), but that's the whole point of the program and controls the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string neighbors[4];` is stack allocated. When you go out `getNeighbors`it looses scope. Try to put it other place (even globaly, just as a proof of concept). A better design should be pass this as parater to your function.

```
void getNeighbors(int string, int member, std::vector<std::string>& neighbors){
      ;
      neighbors[0]=grid[string-1].substr(member,1);//up
      neighbors[1]=grid[string+1].substr(member,1);//down
      neighbors[2]=grid[string].substr(member-1,1);//left
      neighbors[3]=grid[string].substr(member+1,1);//right
    }
```

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <fstream>

    std::string grid[20]={" "};
    std::string neighbors[4]; //<---------------------------

    std::string get(int string, int member){
      return grid[string].substr(member,1);
    }
    std::string* getNeighbors(int string, int member){
      neighbors[0]=grid[string-1].substr(member,1);//up
      neighbors[1]=grid[string+1].substr(member,1);//down
      neighbors[2]=grid[string].substr(member-1,1);//left
      neighbors[3]=grid[string].substr(member+1,1);//right
      std::string* p=neighbors;
      return p;//Returns up,down,left,right.
    }
    int main(int argc, char** argv){
      grid[1]="@----^---0";
      grid[2]="abcdefghi0";
      grid[3]="jklmnopqr0";//TODO Change to read of txt*/
      std::string* neighbors;
      for(int i=0;grid[1].length()>i;i++){
        neighbors=getNeighbors(2,1);
        if(neighbors[3]=="-" | neighbors[3]=="^"){
          std::string r=get(1,i);
          (r!="0") ? std::cout<<r:"0";//Dangerous. TODO Unknown symbol handling
          std::cout<<neighbors[3];
        }
      }
    }
```

The `neighbors`now is global (I don´t like this, but do the job for the POC).

Comment: You are using a vector as the parameter, but my variable is a std::string* which i use as an array. Could you clarify how to implement your vector with my code?

Answer (score 0):

getNeighbors() is returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: I tried declaring neighbors as a global variable outside of any functions and referencing it with ::neighbors inside of getNeighbors(). This had no effect and still returned segmentation fault 11.